# Parse different objects with same tag in JSON string using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a `REST call` which returns separate **JSON's** for success and failure conditions.

```
Success - {"server_method_name":"{\"Master_Tag\":{\**"Table\":[{\"CustomerID\":000000}]**}}"}

Failure - {"server_method_name":"{\"Master_Tag\":{\**"Table\" : [{\"Status\" : \"False\"}]**}}"}
```

The difference is in the **"Table"** tag as it contains different type of data. 
How can I parse this and determine what the "**Table**" tag contains ?

I am using **GSON** library and this is an Android application.

EDIT: 
Class structure -

To parse the server method name

```
public class ParseCustomerLoginResponseMethodName {

@SerializedName("server_method_name")
private String mMethodName;

/**
 *
 */
public ParseCustomerLoginResponseMethodName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @return the methodName
 */
public String getMethodName() {
    return this.mMethodName;
}

/**
 * @param methodName the methodName to set
 */
public void setMethodName(String methodName) {
    this.mMethodName = methodName;
}
```

}

To parse the tag -

```
public class ParseCustomerLoginResponseTag {

@SerializedName("Master_Tag")
private ParseCustomerLoginResponseTable mTable;

/**
 *
 */
public ParseCustomerLoginResponseTag() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @return the table
 */
public ParseCustomerLoginResponseTable getTable() {
    return this.mTable;
}

/**
 * @param table the table to set
 */
public void setTable(ParseCustomerLoginResponseTable table) {
    this.mTable = table;
}
```

}

To parse the data for SUCCESS result -

```
public class ParseCustomerLoginResponseTable {

@SerializedName("Table")
private ArrayList<CustomerLogin> mList;

/**
 *
 */
public ParseCustomerLoginResponseTable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @return the list
 */
public ArrayList<CustomerLogin> getList() {
    return this.mList;
}

/**
 * @param list the list to set
 */
public void setList(ArrayList<CustomerLogin> list) {
    this.mList = list;
}
```

}

To parse ERROR response -

```
public class ParseJsonErrorResponse {

@SerializedName("Status")
private String mStatus;

/**
 *
 */
public ParseJsonErrorResponse() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @return the status
 */
public String getStatus() {
    return this.mStatus;
}

/**
 * @param status the status to set
 */
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.mStatus = status;
}
```

}

Using above class structure I can parse the SUCCESS condition. 
I am not able to figure out where to use the ParseJsonErrorResponse class , Is the class structure wrong to parse the ERROR condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Make your holder class have two atributes:

```
public class Table(){ 
 boolean Status;
 long CustomerID;
}
```

And you have to check if its not null.